# How to set cookies to client at the first time the client request the html in server-side-render(nextjs+express)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, frontend, next.js

New to Node.js and I'm using nextjs+express+PHP-APi to implement SSR,
**I need node-server to set cookies to client at the first time when the client request the node-server for the home page html, but it works in development mode but doesn't work at production mode**

I'm converting an old protect(CSR) to SSR
In the old logic, when client first request our PHP server, it'll set cookies(uuid) along with the response, which means the client has completed  the identity authentication, then, every request will bring the cookie.

and now in SSR, the node-server should do that stuff, I create a checkAuth function as the authentication middleware, when the client doesn't bring the uuid cookie with the first request, the node-server should request PHP-server for some data and then use the data as cookie along with the response.

now, it works in development mode, it can set cookie to localhost domain successfully,  but doesn't work at production mode

```js
const checkAuth = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    if (req) {
      res.setHeader(
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
        dev ? "localhost" : "[production jost]"
      );
      res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
      res.setHeader(
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
        "Content-Type,Content-Length, Authorization, Accept,X-Requested-With"
      );
      res.setHeader(
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
        "PUT,POST,GET,DELETE,OPTIONS"
      );
      if (req.headers && !req.headers.cookie) {
        const response = await axios({
          //... get data for cookie
        });
        const options = {
          domain: req.headers.req,
          path: "/",
          secure: false,
          httpOnly: true,
          expires: new Date(Date.now() + 7200),
          maxAge: 7200
        };
        res.cookie("uuid", response.data.uuid, options);
      }
      next();
    } else {
      next();
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return res.redirect("/");
  }
};


// ...other code
server.get("/", checkAuth, (req, res) => {
  const actualPage = "/";
  const queryParams = {};
  return app.render(req, res, actualPage, queryParams);
});
```

Comment: Try inspecting the GET request result, does `Set-Cookie` header exist in the response?

Comment: no, the Set-Cookie header  doesn't exist in the response

Comment: since you are checking `req.headers.cookie`, does any cookie (even if not yours) exist in your request header?

Comment: I'm sure that there's no other cookies,and to ensure that it's clean ,I will clean the cookies in the browser